# Polyphase sort and merge order of 3

Tags: sorting

Quick question about Polyphase sorting. Do you write the files sequentially? Like so:

F1: 10 13 7 8 9 4 3 17 18 2

F2: -

F3: -

F4: -

This:

F1: -

F2: 10 13 7 8

F3: 9 4 3 17

F4: 18 2

or do you alternate? vs. this?

F1: -

F2: 10 8 3 2

F3: 13 9 17

F4: 7 4 18

or does it not matter?

Comment: Certainly it matters. Part of the definition of polyphase merge is how the runs are distributed to tapes. You have to use the general Fibonacci distribution. Otherwise it isn't polyphase, it is just guesswork.

Comment: @user207421 - the question was about the order records are distributed, not about the number of records to write to each file.

Answer (score -1):

For any particular set of inputs, your choice of how you split up the initial input will definitely influence the number of passes you need to make in some cases, but in the general sense, it should not matter - some will be slightly better with one method over the other, some will be slightly worse. In the end the average case over all possible inputs will be the same.

However, what the second method has going for it is that you do not have to pre-scan the input to count elements in order to figure out how many elements to put in each bucket.

Comment: Certainly it matters. Part of the definition of polyphase merge is how the runs are distributed to tapes. You have to use the general Fibonacci distribution. Otherwise it isn't polyphase, it is just guesswork.